# Jersey tries to pick up my client interfaces and create a server from them

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, weblogic

I'm porting a multi-module application from Weblogic 10.3.6 to 12.2.1.2.0 and have problems with some of my modules. This seem to concern those modules that doesn't serve REST services themselves, but who are REST-service clients. On application startup they will stop with the stacktrace below.

From the stacktrace we can se that it is 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler' that issues the fault. However, I'm not implementing REST services in this module. It seems to have discovered the client interfaces through the class annotation *@PATH*. If I leave out the class annotations everything will start up just fine. Then of course my client paths will be missing some elements.  Does anybody know how to prevent weblogic/jersey from doing this?

An excerpt from one of my interfaces:

```
@Path("/v1/batch")
@Produces(BatchJobRestService.JSON)
@Consumes(BatchJobRestService.JSON)
public interface BatchJobRestService {
    String JSON = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8";

    @GET
    @Path("runAffectedMunicipalities")
    boolean runAffectedMunicipalities();
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused By: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[HINT] A HTTP GET method, public abstract void no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.BatchJobRestService.setMunicipalitiesSimplifiedGeometriesDryRun(boolean), returns a void type. It can be intentional and perfectly fine, but it is a little uncommon that GET method returns always "204 No Content".; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.BatchJobRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract void no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.BatchJobRestService.setMunicipalitiesSimplifiedGeometriesDryRun(boolean), parameters=[Parameter [type=boolean, source=dryRun, defaultValue=null]], responseType=void}, nameBindings=[]}', [HINT] A HTTP GET method, public abstract void no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.BatchJobRestService.setCountiesSimplifiedGeometriesDryRun(boolean), returns a void type. It can be intentional and perfectly fine, but it is a little uncommon that GET method returns always "204 No Content".; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.BatchJobRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract void no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.BatchJobRestService.setCountiesSimplifiedGeometriesDryRun(boolean), parameters=[Parameter [type=boolean, source=dryRun, defaultValue=null]], responseType=void}, nameBindings=[]}', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findRoadReferenceAndGeometryForPlace(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadType,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findRoadReferenceAndGeometryForPlace(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadType,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId), parameters=[Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=id, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory, source=roadCategory, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber, source=roadNumber, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadType, source=roadType, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId, source=county, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId, source=municipality, defaultValue=null]], responseType=java.util.List<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.RoadReferenceAndGeometry>}, nameBindings=[]}', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findRoadDirections(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_
ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadType,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId) at index 9.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findRoadDirections(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadType,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,java.math.BigDecimal,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId), parameters=[Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory, source=road-category, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber, source=road-number, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadType, source=road-type, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId, source=county, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId, source=municipality, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.math.BigDecimal, source=easting-from, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.math.BigDecimal, source=northing-from, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.math.BigDecimal, source=easting-to, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.math.BigDecimal, source=northing-to, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=place-id-from, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=place-id-to, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=place-public-id-from, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=place-public-id-to, defaultValue=null]], responseType=java.util.List<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.location.Direction>}, nameBindings=[]}', [WARNING] Return type, java.util.List<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference<? extends no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId>>, of method, public abstract java.util.List<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference<? extends no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId>> no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlaceReferences(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RegionId,java.util.Set<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory>,java.util.Set<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber>,java.util.Set<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadType>,java.util.Set<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId>,java.util.Set<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId>,java.lang.String,boolean), is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlaceReferences(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RegionId,java.util.Set,java.util.Set,java.util.Set,java.util.Set,java.util.Set,
java.lang.String,boolean)', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public abstract no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.place.PlaceOrig no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlacesFull(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.place.PlaceOrig no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlacesFull(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId), parameters=[Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=id, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.place.PlaceOrig}, nameBindings=[]}', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public abstract no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlace(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlace(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId), parameters=[Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=id, defaultValue=null]], responseType=no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference<? extends no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId>}, nameBindings=[]}', [WARNING] Return type, no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference<? extends no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId>, of method, public abstract no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference<? extends no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId> no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlace(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId), is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public abstract no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.placereference.PlaceReference no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlace(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId)', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlacePublicFromList(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,boolean) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlacePublicFromList(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double,no.
xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,boolean), parameters=[Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=id, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId, source=municipalityId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId, source=countyId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Double, source=easting, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Double, source=northing, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId, source=municipalityIdTo, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId, source=countyIdTo, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Double, source=eastingTo, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Double, source=northingTo, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory, source=roadCategory, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber, source=roadNumber, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=boolean, source=extended, defaultValue=null]], responseType=java.util.List<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.location.PlacePublic>}, nameBindings=[]}', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlacePublicToList(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,boolean) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract java.util.List no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.findPlacePublicToList(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,boolean), parameters=[Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=id, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=placePublicFromId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId, source=municipalityId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId, source=countyId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Double, source=easting, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Double, source=northing, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory, source=roadCategory, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber, source=roadNumber, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=boolean, source=extended, defaultValue=null]], responseType=java.util.List<no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.location.PlacePublic>}, nameBindings=[]}', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public abstract java.lang.String no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.buildMapRequest(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.
PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RegionId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json;charset=utf-8], producedTypes=[text/plain], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=interface no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService, handlerConstructors=[]}, definitionMethod=public abstract java.lang.String no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.api.RoadDataRestService.buildMapRequest(no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RegionId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId,no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId), parameters=[Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=fromPlaceId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.PlaceId, source=toPlaceId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.enums.RoadCategory, source=roadCategory, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RoadNumber, source=roadNumber, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.RegionId, source=regionId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId, source=fromMunicipalityId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.MunicipalityId, source=toMunicipalityId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId, source=fromCountyId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class no.xxxxxxxxx.yyyy.location_ng.model.id.CountyId, source=toCountyId, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2054)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2031)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1920)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3091)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1823)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:882)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:750)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:627)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:347)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:901)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:456)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:666)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to throw two incantantations to get around this problem. First add this resource config:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ServerAutoDiscoveryDisableResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    {
        property(CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE_SERVER, true);
    }
}
```

... then I also had to lower web.xml version from 2.5 to 2.4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    ...
</web-app>
```

**Update**

I found that what was working is not the property, but the empty REST-service started with the ApplicationPath annotation. However I found the hard way that it was not a great idea to use the root path ("/") as it will shadow all other servlets with lower priority. Instead I used the "/dummy"-path:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/dummy")
public class ServerAutoDiscoveryDisableResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
}
```